# Post-Build Addition of IHostedService

Tags: c#, .net-core, ihostedservice, .net-8.0

Is it possible to add an IHostedService to an IHost after calling HostApplicationBuilder.Build() and IHost.StartAsync()?

The application needs to be able to load plug-ins during use and have services provided in those plug-ins become hosted by the already-started IHost.  Is this possible?

Comment: What kind of high-end feature are you trying to implement? Instead of trying a new IHostedService for new libraries you could have them post "jobs" to the same job queue service, or register callbacks to the same timed service. A more powerful option would be to use HangFire, Coravel or another scheduling library for scheduled jobs and have the plugins register the jobs they want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK - no, at least in non-brittle way. The `IHostedService` infrastructure is build on top of the DI and build-in DI container is immutable after it has been build. Even if you substitute the container with some which allows runtime management of dependencies it still will not work because the`IHostedService`'s are resolved and started upon the application start ([docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio#ihostedservice-interface), [internal `Host` implementation starting services](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/7287238859e2c9d806b63a3fd67f9ec585cf5e24/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting/src/Internal/Host.cs#L125)):

> The hosted service is activated once at app startup

So working over default infrastructure to "just add" the hosted service is not possible.

> The application needs to be able to load plug-ins during use and have services provided in those plug-ins become hosted by the already-started IHost. Is this possible?

But this requirement is totally satisfiable - just create a hosted service which will somehow (depended on your needs) determine/watch new plugins available and manage them (start and stop). Those plugins can be build over standard `IHostedService` interface or any one you deem appropriate. Something to get you started:

```
public class PluginWorker : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly ILogger<PluginWorker> _logger;
    private readonly List<IHostedService> _services = new();

    public PluginWorker(ILogger<PluginWorker> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            IHostedService newOne = await GetNewPlugin(stoppingToken);
            _services.Add(newOne);
            await newOne.StartAsync(stoppingToken);
        }
    }

    public override async Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        await base.StopAsync(cancellationToken);
        await Task.WhenAny(
            Task.WhenAll(_services.Select(s => s.StopAsync(cancellationToken)).ToArray()), 
            Task.Delay(Timeout.Infinite, cancellationToken));
    }

    // TODO:
    private Task<IHostedService> GetNewPlugin(CancellationToken ct) => throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

Comment: That approach is similar to one thing I was considering.  My hesitancy with that is that types provided by the plug-in wouldn't be available for DI.  I'd prefer a solution that allows plugins to have full access to the DI container.  I think my real problem comes down to logging - logging is provided by the HostApplicationBuilder/IHost, so any code that has to run before that (letting the plugins inject their types into the builder) is not going to share the same logging.  Thinking of having 2 hosts (with re-used logging setup) to get around that.

Comment: @PatrickV then I would recommend to go with custom interface which will accept `ILogger` instance or logging factory for `StartAsync` equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

In the unlikely event anyone else needs to build a similar house of cards, the only solution I came up with to this was to have two HostApplicationBuilders.  The first one exclusively dealt with setting up the initial plug-ins.  What it composed was then used as an input into the second builder.  The only reason this was needed was because we needed to dynamically detect and load plug-ins, and we wanted logging to be working the same throughout the life of the application, including during plug-in discovery.  For DI to know about the plug-ins, they had to be available before DI composition, but logging is not available until after DI composition.  This approach did seem to work, but our need to support plug-ins went away, so it was never really fully tested.